# Using a daily updated JSON file with AWS Cloudfront

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

Looking for the solution to get a Cloudfront CDN on a JSON file which is updated daily.

My AWS EC2 server is UK based. I generate a daily JSON file which is automatically sent to S3, as my app is aimed at Asia i am looking to use Cloudfront for speed at their end.

Is there a timed caching/refresh option with Cloudfront I can use with a daily file? The file is sent to S3 at 5am everyday.

I did try creating an invalidation, but it just deleted the cloudfront url access.

Comment: *"it just deleted the cloudfront url access."*  I don't understand what that means.  An invalidation is the correct way to force objects out of cache so that on the next request, a new copy is fetched from the origin.

Comment: But wouldn't result in downtime in between my deletion and the new upload and cache update across the regions? Looking for a zero downtime solution, if possible, that refreshes cache when new file is uploaded

Comment: No. This is zero-downtime.  An invalidation event simply flags any already-cached responses as no longer usable, so that the next request that arrives at any given edge will cause that edge to a check for fresh data for its cache by sending a new request to S3 to fetch the content, return it to the requester, and store it in the local cache.  CloudFront does not push content to the edges -- there are close to 100 independent caches around the globe, in two nested tiers.  Content is cached where it is requested, when it is requested.

Comment: So at 5.01am if I request my JSON file via the Cloudfront URL. It will serve the new file and not the old one which was overwritten?

Comment: That's the general idea, except for the timing of the invalidation request, which takes several minutes to process.  How early can you release the 05:00 file? Would it, say, be possible to release it at 04:30? Or is precision a factor?  Also, I am testing another idea to verify that it works as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of use case where you need high availability , frequently changing content , zero downtime And correct content at every hit... I will suggest setting cache-control metadata to 0

Doing this cloud front will re-validate the content every time and load new content if it finds anything new.